# Can one automatically write a Rails migration for a table change via command line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rake

Is there a way to write this in the command line that will auto-generate the migration script below?

Example:

```
ruby script/generate migration renamePostsTableToActicles
```

Generates:

`class RenamePostsTableToActicles < ActiveRecord:Migration
  def self.up
    rename_table :posts, :articles
  end
  def self.down
    rename_table :articles, :posts
  end
end`

Like:

```
ruby script/generate migration addCategoryIdToPosts category_id:integer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rails migrations currently stand (including Rails 3), no, this isn't possible. Unless there is a plugin out there I'm not aware of.